# count boolean column, and average another column based on boolean column

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, average

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    calculate_time int4 NULL,
    status bool NULL
);

INSERT INTO test (calculate_time,status) VALUES 
(10,true)
,(15,true)
,(20,true)
,(20,true)
,(5,false)
,(10,false)
,(15,false)
,(100,NULL)
,(200,NULL)
,(300,NULL)
;
```

With this query it average all calculated_time values. Is there a way I can tell it only average ones where status = true? I tried adding a where clause but would make failed and suspended result in 0.

```
select 
    avg(calculate_time) as cal_time,
    count(case when status = true then 1 end) as completed,
    count(case when status = false then 1 end) as failed,
    count(case when status is null then 1 end) as suspended
from test;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to understand the concept of conditional aggregation.  You can just also use a `CASE` expression for the average as you did for the other terms in your select:

```
select 
    avg(case when status then calculate_time end) as cal_time,
    count(case when status then 1 end) as completed,
    count(case when not status then 1 end) as failed,
    count(case when status is null then 1 end) as suspended
from test;
```

This works because the `AVG` function, like most of the other aggregate functions, ignore `NULL` values.  So the records for which `status` is not true, their `calculate_time` values would be effectively ignored and would not influence the overall average.

Other side note: You may use boolean values in a Postgres query directly without comparing them to `true`.  That is, the following two `CASE` expressions are equivalent, with the second one being less terse:

```
avg(case when status = true then calculate_time end) as cal_time,
avg(case when status then calculate_time end) as cal_time,
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Tim's answer, since Postgres 9.4 you can add a `filter` clause to aggregate function calls, which may save you some of the boiler-plate of writing your own `case` expressions:

```
select
    avg(calculate_time) filter (where status) as cal_time,
    count(*) filter (where status) as completed,
    count(*) filter (where not status) as failed,
    count(*) filter (where status is null) as suspended
from test;
```

Comment: I'm trying to memorize this now +1.